# Converting Flat JSON To Parent-Child relational Structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, treeview

we want to convert Below JSON to Parent-Child Relation for a tree view structure, based on parent Link and Display Order.

1. if parent link is empty it is parent
2. if parent link exist it should add as a child
3. items should sort based on display order

```
[{
  "ParentLink":{ },
  "Id":1,
  "Title":"Home ITSD test new",
  "Url":{
     "Description":"#",
     "Url":"https://technologies.sharepoint.com/"
  },
  "DisplayOrder":1,
  "IsActive":true,
  "ID":1},{
  "ParentLink":{

  },
  "Id":2,
  "Title":"Link6",
  "Url":{
     "Description":"#",
     "Url":"https://technologies.sharepoint.com/"
  },
  "DisplayOrder":2,
  "IsActive":true,
  "ID":2},{"ParentLink":{
     "Title":"Link6"
  },
  "Id":3,
  "Title":"link7",
  "Url":{
     "Description":"#",
     "Url":"https://technologies.sharepoint.com/"
  },
  "DisplayOrder":21,
  "IsActive":true,
  "ID":3},{
  "ParentLink":{
     "Title":"Link6"
  },"Id":4,
  "Title":"link8",
  "Url":{
     "Description":"#",
     "Url":"https://technologies.sharepoint.com/"
  },
  "DisplayOrder":22,
  "IsActive":true,
  "ID":4},{
  "ParentLink":{
     "Title":"link8"
  },
  "Id":5,
  "Title":"link9",
  "Url":{
     "Description":"#",
     "Url":"https://technologies.sharepoint.com/"
  },
  "DisplayOrder":221,
  "IsActive":true,
  "ID":5}]
```

is there any other libraries already available or any easy way to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `Title` and `ParentLink.Title` do not have matching values, you could take both values as lower case letters and use both to generate a tree by iterating the given array and use an object for assigning nodes and children.

For the wanted order, I suggest to sort the data in advance and take the nodes as the actual order for generating the tree. This is easier than to sort later only parts.

<sub>Just wondering, why has the data two id properties?</sub>

```js
var data = [{ ParentLink: {}, Id: 1, Title: "Home ITSD test new", Url: { Description: "#", Url: "https://technologies.sharepoint.com/" }, DisplayOrder: 1, IsActive: true, ID: 1 }, { ParentLink: {}, Id: 2, Title: "Link6", Url: { Description: "#", Url: "https://technologies.sharepoint.com/" }, DisplayOrder: 2, IsActive: true, ID: 2 }, { ParentLink: { Title: "Link6" }, Id: 3, Title: "link7", Url: { Description: "#", Url: "https://technologies.sharepoint.com/" }, DisplayOrder: 21, IsActive: true, ID: 3 }, { ParentLink: { Title: "Link6" }, Id: 4, Title: "link8", Url: { Description: "#", Url: "https://technologies.sharepoint.com/" }, DisplayOrder: 22, IsActive: true, ID: 4 }, { ParentLink: { Title: "link8" }, Id: 5, Title: "link9", Url: { Description: "#", Url: "https://technologies.sharepoint.com/" }, DisplayOrder: 221, IsActive: true, ID: 5 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var id = a.Title.toLowerCase(),
                parent = a.ParentLink && a.ParentLink.Title && a.ParentLink.Title.toLowerCase();

            a.children = o[id] && o[id].children;
            o[id] = a;
            if (parent === root) {
                r.push(a);
            } else {
                o[parent] = o[parent] || {};
                o[parent].children = o[parent].children || [];
                o[parent].children.push(a);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, undefined);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina Scholz, you saved my day